# <noscript> tags in django - python is not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm totally a newbie to Django-Python.

So, whenever I include my  tag like this,

```
<noscript>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'homepage/css/style.css'%}" />
</noscript>
```

Browser doesn't take the code in noscript tag. Whereas, if I load that HTML file independently, there are no issues with the same browser.

Tried different ways,

```
<script>
  var url = "{% static 'homepage/css/style' %}";
</script>
```

Didn't help though!

Please push me to pass through this bump!

Many thanks!

Comment: did you take right path of CSS in static templatetag?

Comment: can you share the error message?

Comment: at the top of the template did you used this {% load static %}

Comment: I did it the right way in css static template tag. @neeraj..

Comment: Also there was no error message displayed, it's just the HTML page in the browser wasn't displaying as expected